# how to use an array like a size or dimension in another array of 2D in C++

Tags: c++

i have a set of Jobs J= 10 , and h is the index of J , Each job h is executed exactly in one mode m in M(h) where m stands for the number of workers assigned to the job h and is related to a processing time Pjob(h,m).

can anybody help me and fix it and how to use M(h) in For loop

So this my code of declaration:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

#define J 10   
int h; // index of Job J 
int m; // index of Mode M

int M[J] = { 2, 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 1 , 3, 3 , 2 , 1 };// index m
int Pjob[J][M[J]];// processing time for job h performed in mode m
```

so it shows me an errors   and i thought that the declaration was fault:

`Error (active) E0028 expression must have constant value Error C2131 expression was not evaluated to constant Error C2148 total array size must not exceed 0x7ffffffff bytes`

can anybody help me and fix it and how to use M(h) in For loop

Comment: Just use `std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` and skip the headaches.

Comment: The expression `M[J]` exhibits undefined behaviour as `M` was defined as `int[J]`, so everything past position `J-1` is out of bounds.

Comment: What is the size of Pjob?

Comment: You can change `M` to be `constexpr M[J] = ...;`, then it is a compile time constant when using `M[index]`. Only when `index` is also a constant...

Comment: All array elements must have the same type, and that also applies when those array elements happen to be arrays.

Comment: the size of Pjob[J][M[h] ] and when M[h] is size 10 so Pjob[10][10] so 10*10 @stark

Comment: @aschepler a vector for M[J] or for the processing time Pjob [J][M[J] ???

Answer (score 0):

Arrays must have regular dimensions (meaning, they must be square, or cubic, etc). Just declare your `Pjob` array to have the largest regular size:

```
#define J 10
#define MAX_MJ 5
int M[J] = { 2, 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 1 , 3, 3 , 2 , 1 };// index m
int Pjob[J][MAX_MJ];// processing time for job h performed in mode m
```

Then use it with your special indexing:

```
assert(job < J);
assert(mode < M[job]);
quux( Pjob[job][mode] );
```

This wastes space for unused elements, but for such a small object it is unlikely to be a problem.

The other option is to use a `std::vector` or other library container.